# Javascript function keeps executing even after c

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a code where I have 3 divs each contain 2 animated progress bars.

I also have 3 buttons. On each of that a specific functions runs which hides the 2 divs out of 3.

So here is the issue, when I click on a button a single div shows with animated bars. But, when I click on second button before the first progress bars animation completes. On the second button click first function should be stopped but it keeps running and makes the progress bars looks shaking.

If I put another function in javascript and run one of them on a click... the first function should end but it's not happening.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
var elem2 = document.getElementById("myBar2");
var elem41 = document.getElementById("myBar41");
var elem3 = document.getElementById("myBar3");
var elem4 = document.getElementById("myBar4");
var elem5 = document.getElementById("myBar5");
var elem42 = document.getElementById("myBar42");
var elem6 = document.getElementById("myBar6");
var elem7 = document.getElementById("myBar7");
var elem43 = document.getElementById("myBar43");
var elem8 = document.getElementById("myBar8");
var elem9 = document.getElementById("myBar9");
var elem44 = document.getElementById("myBar44");
var elem10 = document.getElementById("myBar10");
var elem11 = document.getElementById("myBar11");
var elem12 = document.getElementById("myBar12");
var elem13 = document.getElementById("myBar13");
var elem14 = document.getElementById("myBar14");
var elem15 = document.getElementById("myBar15");
var elem45= document.getElementById("myBar45");

function move() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 0);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move2() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 2);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem2.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem2.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move3() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 6);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem3.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem3.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move41() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 4);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem41.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem41.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
move();move2();move3();move41();
function moveAll(){  
    move();move2();move3();move41();

    document.getElementById("WebDownNone").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("DownMusikNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownBookNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownUpdateNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownFotoNone").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("oneMove").addEventListener("click", moveAll);

function move101() {

    document.getElementById("WebDownNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownMusikNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownBookNone").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("DownUpdateNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownFotoNone").style.display = "none"; 


    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem4.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem4.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move102() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem5.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem5.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move103() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 27);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem6.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem6.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move42() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 16);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem42.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem42.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}

function moveAll100(){  
    move101();move102();move103();move42();
}
document.getElementById("twoMove").addEventListener("click", moveAll100);



function move201() {

    document.getElementById("WebDownNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownMusikNone").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("DownBookNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownUpdateNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownFotoNone").style.display = "none"; 

    var width = 0;
     elem.style.width = width + '%';
    var id = setInterval(frame, 40);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            elem.style.width = 0;
            width++; 
            elem7.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem7.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move202() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 80);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem8.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem8.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move203() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 270);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem9.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem9.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move43() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 160);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem43.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem43.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}


setTimeout(()=>{
moveAll100();
},1000)
function moveAll200(){ 

    move201();move202();move203();move43();
}

document.getElementById("threeMove").addEventListener("click", moveAll200);




function move301() {

    document.getElementById("WebDownNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownMusikNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownBookNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownUpdateNone").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("DownFotoNone").style.display = "none";  

    var width = 0;
     elem.style.width = width + '%';
    var id = setInterval(frame, 100);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            elem.style.width = 0;
            width++; 
            elem10.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem10.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move302() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 200);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem11.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem11.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move303() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 670);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem12.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem12.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move44() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 400);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem44.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem44.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function moveAll300(){  

    move301();move302();move303();move44();
}

document.getElementById("fourMove").addEventListener("click", moveAll300);



function move401() {

    document.getElementById("WebDownNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownMusikNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownBookNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownUpdateNone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DownFotoNone").style.display = "block";

    var width = 0;
     elem.style.width = width + '%';
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            elem.style.width = 0;
            width++; 
            elem13.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem13.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move402() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 20);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem14.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem14.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move403() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 80);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem15.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem15.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function move45() {
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 80);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem45.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem45.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
function moveAll400(){

    move401();move402();move403();move45();
}

document.getElementById("fiveMove").addEventListener("click", moveAll400);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you will have only one interval at a time you can clear the interval before starting the newer one, you can create the global variable to startwith and clear on second one starts.

To explain what I did is,

move the id out of the function

```
var id = null; //this will be a global variable now
```

then, assign the setinterval to id variable in each and every function,

```
id = setInterval(frame, 1000);//assigning
```

then, clear the interval before you start this interval in all the functions.

```
clearInterval(id);
```

Remember step2 and 3 you need to do in all functions where you applied the setinterval. inshort, you are just stopping the setinterval.

you need to move the id out of the function, apply the id to setinterval in each and every function you want to execute, and  clearInterval(id); before you start the

```js
var elem4 = document.getElementById("myBar4");
var elem5 = document.getElementById("myBar5");
var elem3 = document.getElementById("myBar3");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("myBar2");
var elem6 = document.getElementById("myBar6");
var elem7 = document.getElementById("myBar7");

var id = null;

function move() {
  var width = 0;
  clearInterval(id);
  id = setInterval(frame, 1000);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem4.style.width = width + '%';
      elem4.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}

function move2() {
clearInterval(id);
  var width = 0;
  id = setInterval(frame, 1000);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem5.style.width = width + '%';
      elem5.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}

move();
setTimeout(()=>{
move2();
},1000)



function moveAll() {
  move();
  move2();
  document.getElementById("MainDivOne").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("MainDivTwo").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("MainDivThree").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<style>
  .mybar {
    width: 0%;
  }
</style>

<div id="MainDivOne">
  <!-- DIV 1 -->
  <div id="myProgress4">
    <div id="myBar4" class="myBar greenBar">0%</div>
  </div>
  <div id="myProgress5">
    <div id="myBar5" class="myBar yellowBar">0%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="MainDivTwo">
  <!-- DIV 2 -->
  <div id="myProgress3">
    <div id="myBar3" class="myBar greenBar">0%</div>
  </div>
  <div id="myProgress2">
    <div id="myBar2" class="myBar yellowBar">0%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="MainDivThree">
  <!-- DIV 3 -->
  <div id="myProgress6">
    <div id="myBar6" class="myBar greenBar">0%</div>
  </div>
  <div id="myProgress7">
    <div id="myBar7" class="myBar yellowBar">0%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for taking time to answer my question, I've applied the solution to my original code which I have now edited to the question. I know you are right I'm just not sure where to apply the fix. I would be very thankful, if you could check my original code in the question. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: @kalu I updated my answer, you can understand it easily now and apply to your code, hope it should be easy for you now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to put your `var id` out of your functions, so it's a global scope var, acessible trhough your entire script.
At second place, just need to add some code to button EventListener...
The code as follows:

```js
var id = null;
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
var elem2 = document.getElementById("myBar2");

function move() {
  var width = 0;
  id = setInterval(frame, 0);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}
function move2() {
  var width = 0;
  id = setInterval(frame, 2);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem2.style.width = width + '%'; 
      elem2.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("oneMove").addEventListener("click", function(){
 if(id)
  clearInterval(id);
 move();
});
document.getElementById("twoMove").addEventListener("click", function(){
 if(id)
  clearInterval(id);
 move2();
});
```

```css
div {
 border: 1px solid red;
 height: 20px;
 width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBar"></div>
<button id="oneMove">oneMove</button>
<div id="myBar2"></div>
<button id="twoMove">TwoMove</button>
```

Please, note that, in this scope, the button click will stop any previous running function and if clicked twice may produce uggly effect.. you can customize the code to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to return the id of the move function so you can use clearInterval() when starting an other one.

Return the id in move1()

```
function move() {
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 0);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
       clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem4.style.width = width + '%'; 
      elem4.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
  return id;
}
```

Add a parameter to move2()

```
function move2(stopId) {
  // stops the previous move function
  clearInterval(stopId);

  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 2);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem5.style.width = width + '%'; 
      elem5.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  } 
}
```

Then call the functions (i added a timeout to see the difference). Basically, i'm just calling move2 with the id of move1 as a parameter.

```
 var move1Id = move();

 setTimeout(function() {
   move2(move1Id);
 }, 600)
```

To push it a bit, i would advise setting the id parameter as optional in move2().